# Parsing multiple XML web file iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

Let's say i have a xml file with a tag named  which contains the number of fields i want to show in my tableView and in another xml file i have the information to be displayed in that tableView.

The question is : Should i create 2 different file in my project (xmlparse1.h and .m + xmlparse2.h and .m) or should i just put all my code in 1 (xmlparse.h + .m) and differenciate which file i am parsing at the moment with a bool or something like that in the code?

I am developing an iphone app on Xcode 4.3 mac os x 10.7.4 if this might change

EDIT: 1st file :

```
<MenuPrin>
<humidite>82,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</humidite>
<tempmoy>
189,124,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700
</tempmoy>
</MenuPrin>
```

2nd File :

```
<Instal>
<nbrField>2</nbrField>
</Instal>
```

So it looks like this. So, since nbrField is 2 I would take the 2 first value from tempMoy and humidite and show them in a tableView.

END OF EDIT

Comment: Which minimum version of iOS are you going to be targeting?

Comment: Can you post examples of your XML to make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Updated question with xml file example

Comment: Do you have control over the generation of the XML files, or is this just something you are getting from other servers?

Comment: I have no control over it, i get this XML from a controller (a board)

Comment: Edited once more, content of 2nd file was not showing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If how you're parsing is similar in both instances, to add two sets of files that do effectively the same thing would be extremely inefficient and considered bad practice. It makes a lot more sense to create a parser that can handle the two different files than to write two parsers that can only handle a specific file each.

To more specifically answer your question, I would determine which file you are parsing and behave accordingly, whether you do this with a bool or something else is up to you.

**EDIT:** Here is the idea that just popped into my head, so if for whatever reason this wont work for you(Like I said its been a while), or someone has a better idea, I'm all ears. You could still have a set of files(.h and .m) that contain the definition of your parser. Your parser could contain within it a two variables of type Object1 and Object2 which are built in such a way that they resemble the data structure that you need to store what you parse once for your first type of file, and a different definition for your second type of file. This way when parsing once you determine which file it is you are reading, it just changes which of these two objects you write into. There are also plenty of variations for how you could set this up, and I can also think of a few cases for what you might be trying to do where this might not work, but there is the idea regardless.

If you think that the two sets of files approach is better for the application you are trying to write and makes more sense to you, given what has been discussed in the comments, it isn't necessarily a bad idea.

Comment: Please explain why it is "extremely inefficient" and "bad practice"?

Comment: Well if you are writing code that does the same thing, parse XML, why would you write it twice? Perhaps he has a reason to want to rewrite the parser in two different ways, but from his question what that reason is, is unclear to me.

Comment: From what was said in the question, he is trying to parse two different XML files containing different data. So each would have to parse into different objects which would mean requiring to set different instance variables. So they wouldn't be doing the same thing twice.

Comment: It is difficult to explain...Some information taken from file 1 will have effect on information taken from file 2... don't know if it makes things more clear (should i edit my question with this)

Comment: Fair enough, from the XML parsing that I had some albeit brief experience with last year the solution of creating two files that both just parse didn't seem like a good idea, although I didn't create XML objects to parse into, I just parsed my data into a CoreData DB I had set up. I have an idea general idea of how you may be able to still only use one file, though depending on your data, Ben, it may not work for you. The more information you can give us in the question the better we can help you. I'll edit my answer with what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1):

In case if u want to create two table view in one view u need to create a single .h & .m file...If u want to create individual table view u need to create two .h & .m...

Try TBXML parser...that is the easiest way and less memory usage for xmlparsing...